# Extracting cities population dependence from count variables, for regression

Tags: regression, linear-model, model

Suppose that I have a random variable $Y$ which counts the number of employed people for $n$ different cities, i.e. $Y=(Y_{1}, Y_{2},..., Y_{n}).$

Also, I have two independent count variables measured for each city. Those are $X_{1} = (X_{11}, X_{12},..., X_{1n})$ which counts the number of people with a Bachelor degree on each city, and $X_{2} = (X_{21}, X_{22},..., X_{2n})$ which counts the number of people with access to the internet.

My goal is to create a model of the form
$$Y = b_{0} +b_{1}X_{1} + b_{2}X_{2} \ \ \ (*)$$

However, my first goal is to remove the dependence of measurements on the city's population size $Pop_{i}$, and bring all the measurements on the same scale.

Clearly, a city with a larger population ,$Pop_{i}$, is more likely to have more employed people ,$Y_{i}$, more people with Bachelor's degrees ,$X_{1i}$, and more people with access to the internet $X_{2i}$, however, the ratio of employed people compared to the population might be smaller compared to a city with smaller population size.

For example, $Pop_{1}=10.000$ and $Pop_{2}=5000$ and the $Y_{1}=5000, Y_{2}=3000$. Clearly, in the first city, we have more employed people but the percentage of employed people is larger for the second city since $5.000/10.000<3.000/5.000$

---

To sum up I have two concerns,

1. Even though it seems intuitive to have everything on the same scale, i.e. to work with percentages, what is the advantage, why don't we fit the model $(*)$ and just simply ignore the population sizes?
2. Is the following a way to scale everything, equivalently takeout the dependence on the citys population size,

$$Y/Pop = b_{0} + b_{1}X_{1}/Pop + b_{2}X_{2}/Pop$$

3. Is my way of thinking wrong, or do I have to consider something else?

Comment: How about $Y = b_0 + b_1 X_1 + b_2  X_2 + b_3 pop$?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami but again the measurements will be on different scales. Pop will just explain how much the Pop variable contributes